# Is it safe to use the `Function` constructor to validate JavaScript syntax?

Tags: javascript, security, eval, client-side

I would like to verify (client-side) that the user has entered valid JavaScript code.

Pulling in a Javascript parser (e.g. Acorn or Esprima) is a relatively heavy dependency.  However (if CSP is not enabled), I *could* do:

```js
try {
    new Function(userCode);
    return {valid: true}
} catch (e) {
    return {
        valid: false,
        error: e.message
    };
}
```

While this does use `new Function`, the user-provided code is never *run*, only parsed/compiled.  Is there still a security issue?

Comment: I think it's safe. Just defining a function doesn't execute the code.

Comment: @Barmar That's my intuition as well, but JS has some odd corners (which enable `__proto__` pollution and stuff I wouldn't expect) so 

Comment: You can read about the Function constructor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function).  I don't think there are any side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fine. Parsing/compiling JS code is safe and has no side effects (module resolution and loading does not apply in `Function`). We can be certain that JavaScript parsers used in modern browsers are pretty free of bugs.

Answer (score 4):

The standard (even as early as [ECMA-262 1st Ed., §15.3.2.1](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_1st_edition_june_1997.pdf), and all later ones too) specifies that invoking the `Function` constructor will only parse and compile the code it is given, not execute it; so on paper, and in modern, mainstream-browser engines, this should *probably* be fine.  But even under their relatively recent versions (those available as late as 2016), this actually used to be quite unsafe.  Some engines used to implement the `Function` constructor as the moral equivalent of:

```
function Function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join(",");
  var body = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  return (0, eval)("(function anonymous(" + args + "\n) {\n" + body + "\n});");
}
```

with *all* the consequences – in particular, under V8 you could write something like `new Function("}, alert(1), function () {")` and have it execute arbitrary code: see [bug #2470](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2470).  Meanwhile, JavaScriptCore could outright crash when fed invalid code to the constructor: see [bugs #106160](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106160) or [#163748](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163748).  Less mainstream engines may be prone to making the same shortcut even today.  For example, QuickJS does so, and is *still* vulnerable to this trick as of 2024: https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/06651314f5bbef1bb7a2689da7fd7b2b04ce6125/quickjs.c#L38342.

To be safe against such sloppy implementations, you may want to check for known bugs in the `Function` constructor and disable client-side checks if any vulnerabilities are detected.

```js
function isSyntaxCheckingSafe() {
  function check() {
    try {
      Function.apply(null, arguments);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      if (!(e instanceof SyntaxError))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /* this one first, as it does not outright crash buggy JavaScriptCore */
  if (check("/*", "*/){"))
    return false;
  if (check("},function(){"))
    return false;
  if (check("};{"))
    return false;

  /* no problems found, fingers crossed */
  return true;
}

console.log(isSyntaxCheckingSafe());
```

The above tests are prone to generating false-ish positives in that they will judge engines that successfully parse malformed `Function` arguments, but do not actually execute any injected code to be vulnerable.  But better safe than sorry.

---

Note also that there are limitations to this approach other than safety:

- Since the `Function` constructor creates *synchronous* function objects, `await` expressions will be rejected.  If you intend to accept asynchronous code, this can be remedied by using `(async function () {}).constructor` instead of `Function`.
- Code using the `return` statement will always be accepted, even if you intend to later insert it in a non-function context.  There is no work-around for this.
- Module directives like `import` will be rejected.  There is no work-around for this either; one may appear in the future if the [Compartments proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-compartments/) is accepted, which as of this writing (March 2024) is at stage 1 and includes a `ModuleSource` constructor that can parse module code.
- The environment where you validate the code may differ from the one where you eventually use it: a browser engine may support syntax constructs your (one would hope) sandboxed server environment does not, and vice versa.

Given that, such a test should probably be considered a best-effort sanity check at best (just like every other client-side check, really) that will only offload typos.  You should keep independent server-side checks in place, not assume any client-side checks were performed, and even disable client-side checks if the environment available there proves incapable (because of subpar security or missing features).

Comment: Huh. Looks like my "*We can be certain that […] modern browsers are pretty free of bugs.*" was overly optimistic!